# Handling multipe timers in a single timer

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I have around 20 timers on my form, all with different intervals.
For example, one has the interval of 25, one has the interval of 100, but some also have "irregular" intervals like 43.

I would like to have only a single timer and handle everything in its Tick event.

For example like this:

```
Private Sub _TmrAll_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _TmrAll.Tick

    _iTimer += 25

    If _iTimer Mod 25 = 0 Then
        pHandleClickDelayRepeat()
    End If

    If _iTimer Mod 100 = 0 Then
        pHandleSkype()
    End If

    If _iTimer Mod 43 = 0 Then 'this of course would not work with my current approach
        pHandleMouse()
    End If
```

It think my current approach is not really good because I can not easily handle these irregular intervals.

Does anybody have any better idea of how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: The role of the variable __iTimer_ is not clear. what is its purpose?

Comment: Is there a problem with using multiple timers?

Comment: If you need to identify which timer triggers the event to execute a particular task for that timer then you should simply set the Tag property of the timer and execute the code for that timer checking the Tag property

Comment: How do you keep 20 appointments during a day with only a single wrist-watch?  Do it the exact same way, time only the *next* event that is due and when that time is up then handle all of them with the same due time.  You need a SortedList and stop/restart the timer when another due time needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one timer and set the interval to be the largest divisor (with no remainder) of all of the intervals you can.

In your case 43 only divides by 43 or 1. You can't use 43 because that is not a divisor of 25, so your only option is 1. This means it will be firing lots of times when it is doing nothing but that doesn't really matter.

So just keep a track of the interval variable (you can use a Static variable to keep the scope as small as possible). Something like this:

```
Private Sub _TmrAll_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _TmrAll.Tick
    Static intervalCount As Integer = 0

    intervalCount += 1

    If intervalCount Mod 25 = 0 Then
        pHandleClickDelayRepeat()
    End If

    If intervalCount Mod 100 = 0 Then
        pHandleSkype()
    End If

    If intervalCount Mod 43 = 0 Then 
        pHandleMouse()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that some intervals like 43 were saved by the user, and it would mean that the event should be handled each 43 milliseconds. How could I handle this with your approach? A timer can only fire each ~25 ms, so the +1 approach would not work, I think.

Comment: Err. Well the minimum interval on the timer is 1ms, so just use that. I think that you are in the realms of spooling up a task for each of these and waiting asynchronously for the specified amount before executing the required routine now, but I tried to answer your question as it was set

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you always add the value before checking what
should be done.

```
_iTimer += 25
```

has to be written underneath the If conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that _iTimer is a global variable that you use to count the loops you should increment 1 instead of 25. Otherwise you will never hit your "irregular" intervals. You should change the timer interval to 1000 (based on 1 second) and increment 1 by 1 (_iTimer += 1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (known as Rx) for this. Just NuGet "Rx-WinForms".

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim cs = New ControlScheduler(Me)

    Dim subscription1 =
        cs.SchedulePeriodic(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25.0),
            Sub() pHandleClickDelayRepeat())

    Dim subscription2 =
        cs.SchedulePeriodic(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0),
            Sub() pHandleSkype())

    Dim subscription3 =
        cs.SchedulePeriodic(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(43.0),
            Sub() pHandleMouse())

End Sub
```

Rx gives us a bunch of schedulers which can be used directly. I've chosen the `ControlScheduler` which ensures that scheduled events get pushed to the UI thread.

The `ControlScheduler` is effectively the single timer in your app.

You can either use the scheduler directly or make you own observables based on intervals separately, and observe them on the `ControlScheduler`.

```
    Dim cs = New ControlScheduler(Me)

    Dim subscription1 =
        Observable _
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25.0)) _
            .ObserveOn(cs) _
            .Subscribe(Sub() pHandleClickDelayRepeat())

    Dim subscription2 =
        Observable _
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)) _
            .ObserveOn(cs) _
            .Subscribe(Sub() pHandleSkype())

    Dim subscription3 =
        Observable _
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(43.0)) _
            .ObserveOn(cs) _
            .Subscribe(Sub() pHandleMouse())
```

The second approach lets you do all sorts of cool query things.

```
    Dim query =
        From n In Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(193.0))
        Where n * 2 Mod 3 = 1
        Select "Foo" & n * 5

    Dim subscription4 = query.ObserveOn(cs).Subscribe(Sub(x) Me.Label1.Text = x)
```

Whenever you want to stop one of the scheduled actions or observer subscriptions you just call `.Dipose()` on them, like this:

```
    subscription1.Dispose()
    subscription2.Dispose()
    subscription3.Dispose()
    subscription4.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need is to identify which timer triggers the event to execute a particular task for that timer. If this is the case then you should simply set the Tag property of the timer (at design time or when you programmatically create the Timer) and, when the event triggers execute the code expected for the timer that has triggered the event handler.
There is no need to use the timer interval to identify the timer.

```
Private Sub _TmrAll_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _TmrAll.Tick

    Dim tm = CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)

    Select Case tm.Tag.ToString
        Case "Delay"
            pHandleClickDelayRepeat()
        Case "Skype"
            pHandleSkype()
        Case "Mouse"
            pHandleMouse()
        Case Else
            Debug.WriteLine("Tag not expected")
     End Select
End Sub
```